# Can't assign right click to express keys on my Wacom Pro

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm using the Wacom pro medium, and ever since I installed photoshop CC I can't assign the buttons on the left of the drawing area to right click. When I assign it and try to use it in photoshop, it instead thinks that I am left clicking and will draw onto the canvas. I used to use it to choose my brush back in CS6, but now I can't get it to do the same, has anyone else had this problem?